# Regular surface with Curvature mean constant

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

Let $F:R^3->R$ given by $F(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2 - 1$

I wanto to proof that inverse image of F apply at point $0$
is a regular surface with curvature mean constant.

Let me tell you what my first steps towards solution. If I'm making a mistake, let me know

Resolution steps:

1) First of all, we need calcule the Hessian Matrix $H$ of $F$

2) $H$ is symetric, so we would like to calcule the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of $H$.

3) The eigenvalues of H are called principal curvatures and
are invariant under rotation. They are denoted $κa$ and $κb$.

I need confess, the questions is not very clear, to me is more confortable to know what coeficients i'm
working, because this way, i knew what kind of quadratic surface is.
Perhaps we should discuss what conditions $a, b, c$ will have to regular surface with CMC

Comment: At least for the regular surface part - you can use this thereom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem), combined with the fact that the differential is rank 1 (it can only be rank 0 if all x, y, z are 0, in which case ax^2+by^2+cz^2 can't equal 1)

Comment: What makes you think that the (three) eigenvalues of a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix should have anything to do with the (two) principal curvatures of the level surface $F=0$?

Comment: So how can I rearrange or start my proof?